# Reading and writing to files isn't working in C++

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I am basically trying to reverse the contents of a text file. When I run this code, nothing happens. Code:

```
getArguments();
stringstream ss;
ss << argument;
string fileName;
ss >> fileName;
fstream fileToReverse(fileName);
if (fileToReverse.is_open()) {
    send(sock, "[*] Contents is being written to string ... ", strlen("\n[*] Contents is being written to string ... "), 0);
    string line;
    string contentsOfFile;
    while (getline(fileToReverse, line)) {
        contentsOfFile.append(line);
        line = "\0";
    }
    send(sock, "done\n[*] File is being reversed ... ", strlen("done\n[*] File is being reversed ... "), 0);
    string reversedText(contentsOfFile.length(), ' ');
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0,j=contentsOfFile.length()-1;i<contentsOfFile.length();i++,j--) {
        reversedText[i] = contentsOfFile[j];
    }
    contentsOfFile = "\0";
    fileToReverse << reversedText;
    fileToReverse.close();
    send(sock, "done\n", strlen("done\n"), 0);
}
```

fileName is created from user input, and I know that the file exists. It just doesn't do anything to the file. If anyone has any ideas that they would like to share that would be great.

UPDATE:

I now can write reversedText to the file but how can I delete all of the files contents?

Comment: Did you trying to debug it?

Comment: Yes. It looks like all the functions are being run and all the variables are being created, and it compiled without any warnings.

Comment: You are in an error state at the end of the file when you are trying to write to it. I suspect you need to `fileToReverse.clear()` before you can write to it. You probably also want to seek to the start of the file...

Comment: Thank you that worked but the file still has all of its previous content in it as well as the reverse content. Is there a way to clear the entire file?

Comment: In general I'd prefer keeping input and output in separate `std::istream` and `std::ostream` instances. Look at @MatsPetersson's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, when you have read all the input content, your file is in an "error state" (`eof` and `fail` bits set in the status).

You need to clear that with `fileToReverse.clear();`. Your file position will also be at the end of the file, so you need to use `fileToReverse.seekp(0, ios_base::beg)` to set the position to the beginning.

But I, just as g-makulik, prefer to have two files, one for input and one for output. Saves a large amount of messing about.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to debug something like this - saying "all the functions are being run and all the variables are being created, and it compiled without any warnings" isn't really debugging.

Debugging - this doesn't work. Remove bits until you find what doesn't work. Like you said - all variables are what you expect them. So... try and see if, for example, the way you read and write from a file works. Just write a small program that opens a file like you open it, reads from it like you do and then writes... whatever back into it in the same way you do. See if that works.

In other words, try and find the smallest program that reproduces what you see.